# How to prevent line break before H3?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909732/html-css-multilevel-nested-lists-numbering) solution to make a multilevel numbered list outline.

The problem is that I need top level list items to begin with H3 elements and what I get is something looking like

```
1
My heading
1.1 My subelement
```

While, needless to say, what I want is

```
1 My heading
1.1 My subelement
```

I have checked - the problem is in H3 - it prepends itself with line break naturally. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 9):

Heading elements (all of them) are block level by default. Use CSS to change the display to inline or inline-block.

```
h3 {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to solve the problem indeed. The only reason I have not found this myself was I have mistyped the rule when I was trying this...